# Remove particular characters from some string

Tags: symbols, unicode, characters, arabic, arabxetex

Consider this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\begin{document}
    \begin{arab}
إِبرٰهۦمَِ
    \end{arab}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The arabic string إِبرٰهۦمَِ contains so-called `arabic small yeh` (U+06E6) or maybe `arabic small high yeh` (U+06E7), I am not quite sure. Imagine I have a long string which contains many of these characters and I want to strip them down from the output, i.e. the `small yeh` characters don't show up in the output document. I tried `newunicodechar` package but couldn't get it done so far. Does anyone know how to do this properly?

In general: How to do "if encounter certain character show nothing?"

Comment: Are you free to use lualatex, or must you use (arab)xelatex?

Comment: I strongly prefer xelatex

Comment: can't you just replace this char with (nothing) using your latex editor?

Comment: @touhami Another place in the document, I want to show them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The character in the input is U+06E6 defining that to do nothing changes the output, but I can not read either form so I can not tell if this is a good result.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ۦ}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{arab}
إِبرٰهۦمَِ
    \end{arab}

\end{document}
```